# Uncollapse Columns by RowClick

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have setup my table in Tabulator with `responsiveLayout:"collapse"` and `responsiveLayoutCollapseStartOpen:false`.

My table display properly with collapsed columns.
I added `formatter:"responsiveCollapse"` as column and I properly get the column with + and - icons and can manually expand/collapse the columns.

But for usability on a smartphone, the icon renders really a bit small.
I want to add to expand/collapse based on callback `rowClick`.

I found `responsiveCollapse` and `toggleList` in tabulator.js, so I think I know what needs to happen. However I am totally struggling how to return it out of `rowClick`.

Thank you very much for a hint in advance.

In the tabulator constructor I have:

```js
columns:[ 
    { formatter:"responsiveCollapse", width:30, minWidth:30,      
    hozAlign:"center", resizable:false, headerSort:false, responsive:0 },           
    { title:"Ren.", field:"Race_Number", sorter:"number", 
    hozAlign:"center", minWidth:60, widthGrow:1, responsive:0 },
]
```

And basically I want to achieve the some functionality as formatter:"responsiveCollapse" in rowClick:

```js
rowClick:function(e, id, data, row){ 
    //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    //what to do here to achieve same as formatter:"responsiveCollapse"
},
```

Comment: Could you provide some code

Comment: @JPRLCol Added some code

Answer (score 1):

You could copy some of the code from the built-in ***responsiveCollapse*** formatter to achieve this. It will involve accessing some private variables, which is a bit naughty, but it will do the job:

```js
rowClick:function(e, id, data, row){ 
    var config = cell.getRow()._row.modules.responsiveLayout; //get the responsive config object for the row
    var collapseEl = config.element; //get the collapsible element for the row

    if(collapseEl){ //check if the row has any collapsed data

        config.open = !config.open; toggle the open state

        //toggle the collapse element
        if(config.open){
            el.classList.add("open");
            collapseEl.style.display = '';
        }else{
            el.classList.remove("open");
            collapseEl.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had the same idea and found the toggle function, but I was not able to make it work. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.
Your snippet works with the following corrections:
`var config = cell.getRow()._row.modules.responsiveLayout;`
should be
`var config = id._row.modules.responsiveLayout;`

and

`el.classList.add("open");`
should be
`collapseEl.classList.add("open");`

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

this was very helpful, remember to comment out "toggle the open state" and also update
el.classList.remove("open");
to
collapseEl.classList.remove("open");

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to upvote answers you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: You'll notice I didn't just say "thanks" I also improved the answer.

Comment: If you'd like to "improve an answer" please consider suggesting an edit by clicking the "edit" button at the bottom of a post.